# How to run the dependent request multiple times till the desired response is not achieved from request in test in Postman

Tags: api, postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I have Request A and Request B which I have to test in the Postman Test
Condition for testing these API is that Success of Request A is depended on the response of the Request B
When the request A is hit the response from the Request B send the initial value as 2 for attribute 2 then after 30 second the response of value change to 2.1 which is success of test

```
Request A 
Request B 
Response B 
{
 Attribute 1: Value 1
 Attribute 2: Value 2  Value 2.1
 Attribute 3: Value 3
}
```

Code written in Postman Test is below

```
pm.test("Check Success Status",function(){
let i =1;
do{
   pm.sendRequest("Request B",function(err,res){
   var JsonData=res.json();
   if(JsonData.attribute2=="Value 2.1"){
    {
     break;
    }else{
      setTimeout(2000);
    }
 })
   i++;
  }while(i<5)
})
```

Please let me know if I have implemented the correct logic or is there any other way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I would trigger the dependent request inside the body of the previous request like this:

```
pm.sendRequest(postRequest, (error, response) => {
console.log(error ? error : response.json());
console.log("First")

pm.sendRequest(postRequest, (error, response) => {
    console.log(error ? error : response.json());
    console.log("Second")
});
});
```